# Can anyone help me identify this Japanese font?

Tags: font-identification, japanese

It's used on the earthquake warnings. Here's an image:

[image]

**text**: 緊急地震速報 (気象庁)

I have searched all over Google and everything - it can't be found, which is why I am asking here.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: How have you tried looking for it thus far? You're likely to get a good answer if you show more effort in your problem

Comment: I've searched everywhere - I can't find it. I wouldn't be asking if I couldn't find it.

Comment: Neither Whatthefont or Identifont is compatible with Japanese fonts :worried:

Comment: this could very well be an in-house font. NHK outsources font-making apprently, so it may not be publicly available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose that your image was clipped from the NHK newscast. (Below is from a random YouTube video)

[image]

The text in question (#1) seems to be [N-太角ゴシック体](http://www.lambda.co.jp/?p=828), which actually is a dead copy of [ゴナ](http://imadakin1.seesaa.net/article/401936880.html), but still identifiable since they are using another typeface マール (#2) from the same vendor at the same time. The #3 is [ニューセザンヌ](http://fontworks.co.jp/font/classic/newcezanne/B.html) from an irrelevant company.

Both #1 and ゴナ are hardly obtainable, because #1 is provided exclusively for TV superimposition, and ゴナ is only bundled with its vendor's professional-use typesetting machines. You can either purchase ゴナ strings from an [online pay-per-letter outline shop](http://www.net-dtp.com/outline/search_result.asp?pagetype=get&index=11&searchtype=keyword&idstr=&fonttype=0&keystr=&maker=&j1=0&j2=0&j3=0&j4=0&j5=0&j6=0&wa1=0&wa2=0&wa3=0&wa4=0&wa5=0&wa6=0&o1=0&o2=0&o3=0&o4=0&o5=0&o6=0&o7=&ou1=0&ou2=0&ou3=0&ou4=0&ou5=0&ou6=0&ou7=&ital=0&norm=0), or use [新ゴ](https://www.morisawa.co.jp/font/fontlist/details/fontfamily007.html) instead.

Comment: How would you even find that?! *mind blown*

Comment: Holy crap, thanks! How did you even find this?

Comment: For historical reasons, Japanese typography is full of those pre-internet-age in-the-trade typefaces not available for DTP. So no wonder Google is helpless. ゴナ's vendor (写研) even doesn't have its website! But as far as this font, since it once was a kind of de facto standard sans-serif as much as Helvetica, you'll see it almost everyday in your life if you live in Japan.

Comment: Is there **any** way to obtain N-太角ゴシック体 or ゴナ? Or will I have to just go with something that looks similar? Thanks for all your help by the way :)

Comment: Maybe the vendor of N-太角ゴシック体 could sell you the font if you ask through their contact form, but I'm not sure. And for ゴナ, as far as I know, you can only obtain outlines of the specific letters, weight and style you need from the online store I mentioned in my answer. You don't have much chance to get the font itself, unless you have friends in older Japanese typesetting shops, or get a typesetting machine by auction or somehow.

Comment: Of course I don't have them :D -- I wish I did.